# What is this strange item my character started wearing after an update in Sons of the Forest?

Tags: sons-of-the-forest

In *Sons of the Forest*, my character started wearing a strange item after an update, the origin of which I could not determine. Please see this screenshot and see the part circled in red. What is it?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can you make a spear and aim with it? That extends the characters arm so you can get a better view of it more.  But I'm guessing its just clothing...?